# Runtime Error Exception in JBoss

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, jboss7.x, ejb-3.0

I have created a project using JSF, EJB and JBoss a while back which was running successfully.

Now, after a few days, I have configured the JBoss server again and I am trying to start it but it shows the errors below. I have searched for many things but I was not successful.

```
22:46:53,443 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."SmartRealtorsEAR.ear"."SmartRealtorsJSF.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."SmartRealtorsEAR.ear"."SmartRealtorsJSF.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "SmartRealtorsJSF.war" of deployment "SmartRealtorsEAR.ear"
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting reflective information for class com.mb.FileUploadViewMB with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.SmartRealtorsEAR.ear.SmartRealtorsJSF.war:main" from Service Module Loader
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:70)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:117)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:54)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
... 5 more

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/primefaces/event/FileUploadEvent
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:65) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
... 10 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent from [Module "deployment.SmartRealtorsEAR.ear.SmartRealtorsJSF.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
... 15 more
```

**Again in the Later Part I have some more Error**

```
02:24:31,551 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" started (with errors) in 9946ms - Started 159 of 272 services (35 services failed or missing dependencies, 76 services are passive or on-demand)

02:24:31,801 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "SmartRealtorsEAR.ear" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"SmartRealtorsEAR.ear\".\"SmartRealtorsJSF.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"SmartRealtorsEAR.ear\".\"SmartRealtorsJSF.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \"SmartRealtorsJSF.war\" of deployment \"SmartRealtorsEAR.ear\""},"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsDAO]"]}

02:24:31,863 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment SmartRealtorsJSF.war in 59ms
02:24:31,863 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment SmartRealtorsEJB.jar in 60ms
02:24:31,941 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment SmartRealtorsEAR.ear in 151ms
02:24:31,957 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:


JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.subunit."SmartRealtorsEAR.ear"."SmartRealtorsJSF.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."SmartRealtorsEAR.ear"."SmartRealtorsJSF.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "SmartRealtorsJSF.war" of deployment "SmartRealtorsEAR.ear"

02:24:32,035 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"SmartRealtorsEAR.ear\".\"SmartRealtorsJSF.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"SmartRealtorsEAR.ear\".\"SmartRealtorsJSF.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \"SmartRealtorsJSF.war\" of deployment \"SmartRealtorsEAR.ear\""},"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.UserDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.GeneralImageDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ServicesDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.ImageFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureFacadeImp.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.JointVentureFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersFacadeImpMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersFacadeImp.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.CareersFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogDAO.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.DogDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsDAOMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsDAO.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SmartRealtorsEAR.SmartRealtorsEJB.AboutUsDAO]"]}}}
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent.. have you checked that primefaces jars are present?

Comment: Yes Sir,.. i have checked primefaces jars are present,. I think the problem is in deployment as i have shown the later part of the Error ouput, cant figure out help,....

Comment: write all your ear structure

Comment: Did you upgrade your PrimeFaces version and/or your JBoss version?

Answer (score 0):

Your log says: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent

Have you checked that primefaces jars are present? I would look in the lib folder of your SmartRealtorsJSF.war

Comment: Yes Sir,.. i have checked primefaces jars are present,. I think the problem is in deployment as i have shown the later part of the Error ouput, cant figure out help,...